# Convert string to table Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have this table:
`hello = ["hello","world"]`

Now I convert it to a string: `hellostring = str(hello)`

And now I want to convert it back to a table. How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you using `str` to convert it to a string in the first place?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes but someone already answered

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
literal_eval(hellostring)
```

input: `hellostring = "['hello', 'world']"`

output: `['hello', 'world']`

Comment: Yep, you were faster than I :)